# Is there any way to have functions in basic T4 templates?

Tags: .net, code-generation, t4

By *basic* T4 template, I mean not using T4 Toolkit or any of the add-ins.

My T4 is getting a little complicated, but I'd like to keep in self-contained for now.  Is there a way have functions in your T4 template, without referencing external assemblies?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
<#+
    public List<string> Dostuff()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>(); 

        // ...

        return result;
    }
#>
```

Here's a complete example: [Reading a Xml File in T4 Templates](http://web.archive.org/web/20130812005612/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/12/12/reading-a-xml-file-in-t4-templates.aspx)

[Oleg Sych's T4Toolbox](https://github.com/olegsych/T4Toolbox) is a good resource.

Comment: "<#+ #>", excellent, that's what I'm after.  Do you know, can you define types in that *<#+* code block?

Comment: Note that these class feature control blocks have to in the end of your t4-file, otherwise you'll get syntax errors.

Comment: But this does not allow you to render stuff from inside that function, as you would in a PHP function, right? Is this PHP-like behavior possible (e.g. switch between rendering-mode and code-mode within the function definition)? I think it would be handy to allow this somehow for repetitive rendering tasks...

Comment: Microsoft link is broken.